# ¿Cómo retornar el valor de una función en codeignater y obtenerla con una petición Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Tengo una función en uno de mis controladores, que me retorna el resultado de una suma, hago una petición con ajax para obtener el resultado de esa suma para luego hacer una append y mostrarla en mi código html, el problema es que no me muestra ningún resultado al respecto.

El proceso es el siguiente, con JavaScript realizo una petición ajax a mi controlador.
El código de mi controlador es el siguiente:

```
public function sumaMonto()
{
    $data = $_SESSION['carritoFinan'];
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($data as $r) {
      $total = $total + $r->monto;                

    }
    //print($total);
    //echo $total;
    return $total;
}
```

La petición realiza por ajax, debe obtener el valor que devuelve la función anterior, y en el success, la data que me devuelve el response al hacer el append al html, no se muestra nada. 
El código de Ajax es el siguiente:

```
function sumaMontoFin() {
    //alert(url);
    var recurso = "C_pat/sumaMonto";
    var total="";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url + recurso,
        success: function (data) {

            //total=data;
            //console.log(data);

            $("#montoFinal").append(data);                

        }
    });

}
```

El código html es el siguiente:

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-9"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="validationCustom04">Monto de la fuente</label>
                <input align='right' class="form-control" id="montoFinal" name="montoFinal" type="text" disabled>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Este campo no puede estar vacio.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: En que momento estas llamando a esa funcion que ejecuta el ajax?

Comment: En un evento onclick que tengo en otra parte de mi código html

Comment: Verifica el codigo de tu JS, el codigo completo de la consulta ajax de jquery es $.ajax({
   url: '/path/to/file',
   type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
   dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
   data: {param1: 'value1'},
  })
  .done(function() {
   console.log("success");
  })
  .fail(function() {
   console.log("error");
  })
  .always(function() {
   console.log("complete");
  }); 
Verifica que los parametros esten seteados correctamente.

Comment: Si, al hacer el console log si logro hacer la peticion, el problema es que el controlador solo me devuelve los datos cuando pongo el ´echo´, si no pongo el 'echo'  no me devuelve nada

Comment: Es que tienes que imprimir algo, sino te va a devolver en blanco.

Comment: Cuando haces la consulta Ajax lo que hace es ir a buscar la URL como si tu la buscaras en tu navegador, sino imprimes nada en el navegador no vez nada, y lo que imprimes es lo que el Ajax toma como data, por eso tambien esta el set del tpo de dato que va a recibir, json, js, html, etc.